# Coldfusion Server Time vs. SQL Database Server time (problems)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, coldfusion

I have an issue where I need to get responses from users via email, SMS, app, etc. and each medium has their own server times. I am running into problems when these times are off by just 5-10 seconds.

I have been using ColFusion's `#now()#` function, but just having these issues. I would like each environment to reference just one standardized time. Best I could think of is the SQL database since they all share that resource?

I am performing update statements similar to the following:

```
    UPDATE
    WENS.dbo.SMS_MESSAGES 
    SET sms_reply = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstwordmessage#" />
    <cfif LEN(firstwordmessage) neq LEN(msg)>, sms_reply_notes = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#msg#" /></cfif>
    , sms_reply_time = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#now()#">
```

I would like to replace #now()# with some kind of getdate() function.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: And what exactly is stopping you from changing your query?

Comment: And generally speaking, you should avoid using three part names since that adds an additional level of effort if you ever need to support multiple environments. Far better to let the connection determine the database in which your objects reside.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server gives you choices for the current date and time.  They are described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timestamp-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

I always preferred `getdate()` because it was easiest to type.

Comment: I consider more typing to be an anti-pattern. The code that does not exist, you do not maintain. So `GETDATE()` is very much a plus for me. Not to mention, I can program a trigger and have this set automatically. No ColdFusion involved.

Comment: ColdFusion is already involved for the other two fields.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I truly appreciate it. How would I put that in the update query? Would it be simply #getdate()#? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a query param based on CF server time, just call SQL Server's GetDate() function.

```
UPDATE WENS.dbo.SMS_MESSAGES 
SET sms_reply = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#firstwordmessage#" />
    <cfif LEN(firstwordmessage) neq LEN(msg)>
        , sms_reply_notes = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#msg#" />
    </cfif>
    , sms_reply_time = GetDate()
```